# get_theme_file_uri won't add image

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to figure out why my image won't add to the WordPress website I am creating. This course came with other images that will display but not the ones I add as a jpg file. I am not sure why it will add the other jpg images but not the ones I want. Here's my code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="page-banner">
      <div class="page-banner__bg-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo 
      get_theme_file_uri('images/traffic.jpg') ?>)"></div>
      <div class="page-banner__content container t-center c-white">
        <h1 class="headline headline--large">TBS</h1>
        <h2 class="headline headline--medium">Working to make traffic safer</h2>
        <h3 class="headline headline--small">Explore constructing, utlities, and other types of work we do</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn--large btn--blue">Service & Support</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn--large btn--blue">Signs</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn--large btn--blue">Utilities</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am not sure if I need to add more information to this.

Comment: Check the below answer. If it works for you then please approve and upvote the answer so that others can find the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="page-banner">
    <div class="page-banner__bg-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo
get_theme_file_uri('images/traffic.jpg'); height:200px;width:100% ?>)"></div>
      <div class="page-banner__content container t-center c-white">
        <h1 class="headline headline--large">TBS</h1>
        <h2 class="headline headline--medium">Working to make traffic safer</h2>
        <h3 class="headline headline--small">Explore constructing, utlities, and other types of work we do</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn--large btn--blue">Service & Support</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn--large btn--blue">Signs</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn--large btn--blue">Utilities</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Problem is that you are closing `<div>` tag without adding any content in that:

```
<div class="page-banner__bg-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo
get_theme_file_uri('images/traffic.jpg') ?>);"></div>
```

So I have added height and width for showing the background image. Either you can add some content or specify the height and width of that div.

Comment: also, set the width of the div to 100%

Comment: <div class="page-banner__bg-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo
get_theme_file_uri('images/traffic.jpg'); ?>'); height: 100px; with:100%; position:relative;"></div>  (this should work)

Comment: Yes @guu876, It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I added the image to my image folder but it wasn't refreshed in VS editor. If you add images to a folder, make sure to refresh the image folder.